# Alter partition table with 60 million rows of data performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning

I am trying to partition a table with 60 million rows of data based on year.

Specifications:
 MySQL 5.7.1
OS : windows

```
ALTER TABLE full_data PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(ProcessDate))(
    PARTITION years VALUES LESS THAN (2019)
 ) ;
```

For the past one day, the process is running. Could you please help me to improve the performance.
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE full_data` (
    Mobile bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Name varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Barcode varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Batch varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Carton varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Doctype varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL, 
    Rack varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL, 
    ProcessDate datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    KEY Mobile (Mobile,Barcode), 
    KEY MobileBarcode (Mobile,Barcode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; '
```

Comment: No, I do not think so I could see only this task in the task manager, I was just running this query In toad MySQL. It's running since 31 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Such an `ALTER` will take hours to copy all the data from the existing table into a temp table, then swap it into place.  Disk I/O is taking the time.

But why do that partitioning?  Only in rare cases will it provide any performance benefit.  How many years do you have?  What queries do you run against the table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

If you are having performance problems, let's start with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `full_data` (
  `Mobile` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Barcode` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Batch` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Carton` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Doctype` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rack` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProcessDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Mobile` (`Mobile`,`Barcode`),
  KEY `MobileBarcode` (`Mobile`,`Barcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
'

Comment: I want year wise data and the date is till 2014. I am writing an segregation application where I have to segregate based on year.  Could you please suggest me how can I segregate the data based on years.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by segregation and what advantage it will have over simply filtering such as `WHERE ProcessDate >= '2016-01-01' AND ProcessDate < '2016-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR`.

Comment: Segregation: physical form will be classified according to year and this data will be moved to warehouse.

Comment: @raghavendraprasadgudipalli - Moving via "transportable tablespaces"?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not aware of that could you please help me with some documentation where i can adopt it.

Comment: @raghavendraprasadgudipalli - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tablespace-copying.html and https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/09/mysql-5-6-transportable-tablespaces-best-practices/